# Drawing state borders with d3 not working as expected

Tags: d3.js, choropleth, map-projections

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/qmn5e3cb/5/) of my problem. Eventually this is going to have county/zipcode info drawn on it.

I create a projection and a geo path:

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
  .scale(width * 1.3)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

However when I try to add state borders... this happens:

[image]

```
#state-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #333;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}


svg.append('path')
  .datum(topojson.mesh(states, states.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
.attr('id', 'state-borders')
.attr('d', path);
```

I've looked at other examples and they all seem to be doing something similar, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Its almost like the stroke-livejoin isnt working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your geographic data is already projected; it does not need to be projected again. A projection takes unprojected points on a 3d globe and projects them to a 2d space, doing this on data that is already 2d won't work.

Your data doesn't comprise of 3d points (with a coordinate space measured in degrees), but rather has 2d points (with a coordinate space measured in pixels). So we can just use an identity transform as there is no need to modify/project/transform the coordinates. In d3v4+ we could use:

```
var path = d3.geoPath(); // default projection is an identity
```

But with d3v3, the default projection of a geo path is AlbersUsa. So we need to explicitly state we don't want a projection:

```
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(null);
```

This gives us a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up68hyaj/).

That this file is pre-pojected is not immediately self evident. Generally a map that looks like a ball of yarn is a good indicator that you are projecting already projected data.

*Now we may have new problems, working with pre-projected geometry can make sizing difficult, more so in d3v3 - this file is intended for a 960x600 viewport. To automatically scale and center a map based on its features see this [quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14492284/7106086), several of the answers are meant for v3 of d3 ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654988/7106086),[b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691788/7106086)). But this gets much easier with the fitSize method that you can use in d3v4+, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940028/7106086). And for more of a discussion of working pre-projected geometry there is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42430361/7106086). If you intend on overlaying features on top of the preprojected geometry you are probably best to find an unprojected US topo/geojson to simplify things, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067890/7106086).*

Comment: Thank you. I was doing the projection because it was the only way I had yet figured out how to scale the map to the size I wanted. Sadly I am stuck on d3v3 for the foreseeable future. I am going to do some more reading on some of the additional stuff you posted now.